# Palindroms numbers between 1 to 10000

Tags: c++

I want to write a program which displays palindromes numbers between 1 and 10000, I wrote a script which displays if the number typed by the user is a palindrome or no but when I add the for loop it gives me false results
My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int num, reverse = 0, remainder, temp;

for(num=0;num<1000;num++){

 temp = num; 
 cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
 while( temp != 0)
 {
  remainder = temp % 10;
  reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
  temp = temp / 10;
  cout << "remainder = " << remainder << endl;
  cout << "reverse = " << reverse << endl;
  cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
 }

 cout << "Reversed number: " << reverse << endl;

 if (num == reverse) 
  cout << "\n" << num << " is a palindrome number." << endl;
 else
  cout << "\n" << num << " is not a palindrome number." << endl;
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: But your `for` loop is not going from 1 to 10000?

Comment: I guess, that's just for debugging...

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `reverse` at the start of the 2nd iteration of the loop?

Comment: It is much easier and efficient to *construct* the palindromes rather than brute-force all the numbers.

Comment: yes from 1 to 10000

Comment: Move all the variables to most local scope they are needed, and your problem will be fixed. This is good practice anyway.

Comment: Adding to @EugeneSh., if you know the limits beforehand, it is always better to store the palindromic numbers in a list ar hashmap at compile time.

Comment: reverse value at the star is 0

Comment: @Eden Think again (or better yet, check it in your debugger). We ask about second (and every next) loop iteration.

Comment: check out [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog

Comment: i don't understand you !!

Comment: @Eden You never reset value of `reverse`, so for 2nd loop iteration it has value from previous loop, not `0`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes it's going to change in each iteration, 0 is just the intial value

Comment: You want it to be reset for every `for` loop iteration. Otherwise, when you have `num == 2`, `reverse` will be `12`, for `num == 3` `reverse` will be `123` etc. until you start overflowing. It's a really good problem to learn how to use a debugger - if you go through your loop and examine values for each variable, you will notice the problem yourself.

Comment: I don't have errors in my script, but the result in consolt is false

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i understand youuu, can you help to correct my script

Comment: thank youu @Yksisarvinen i correct it hhh

Comment: The compiler mostly verifies grammar. The compiler can't know what you want the code to really do, so getting the logic right is up to you. It is very easy to make grammatically correct statements that are not logically correct. Just watch a political debate or infomercial to see this in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `reverse` is always `0` at the start of loop iteration:

```
for(num=0;num<1000;num++){
 reverse = 0;
 temp = num; 
 cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
 while( temp != 0)
 {
  remainder = temp % 10;
  reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
  temp = temp / 10;
  cout << "remainder = " << remainder << endl;
  cout << "reverse = " << reverse << endl;
  cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
 }

 cout << "Reversed number: " << reverse << endl;

 if (num == reverse) 
  cout << "\n" << num << " is a palindrome number." << endl;
 else
  cout << "\n" << num << " is not a palindrome number." << endl;
 }
```

Managing variables becomes much easier if you declare them where you need them instead of lumping everything together:

```
int main()
{
for(int num=0;num<1000;num++){
 int reverse = 0;
 int temp = num; 
 int remainder = 0;
 cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
 while( temp != 0)
 {
  remainder = temp % 10;
  reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
  temp = temp / 10;
  cout << "remainder = " << remainder << endl;
  cout << "reverse = " << reverse << endl;
  cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
 }

 cout << "Reversed number: " << reverse << endl;

 if (num == reverse) 
  cout << "\n" << num << " is a palindrome number." << endl;
 else
  cout << "\n" << num << " is not a palindrome number." << endl;
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Now you are sure `remainder` is always initialized at the start of `for` loop iteration and it cannot live longer than one iteration (for example, it won't live to the next iteration).

Answer (score 1):

I checked your program and noticed a few flaws:
1) All 1-digit numbers are Palindrome because their is reverse is same.
---Your program didn't display them as palindromes.
2) You don't have to display all the details like their remainder and reverse.
 ---Obviously the Palindromes reverse will be the same as the original. We don't need to display non-palindromes. In some cases reverse was displaying garbage values as well. I don't find a reason that will be of any help to the user.

**Solution:-**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool findPalindrome(const int);
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        if (findPalindrome(i)) {
            cout << "Number " << i << " is a Palindrome!" << endl;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    // Return EXIT_SUCCESS is my Specialty :D 
}
bool findPalindrome(const int num) {
    int temp = num;
    int reve = 0;
    while (temp != 0) {
        reve = (reve * 10) + (temp % 10);
        temp /= 10;
    }
    return (reve == num);
}
```

Comment: @Eden I have solved the problem check if this fits your requirements.

Comment: @Eden Old one is your answer.   New one is my solution

Comment: *In some cases reverse was displaying garbage values as well. I don't find a reason that will be of any help to the user.* Seeing as this was the mistake Eden made you still haven't explained what went wrong and how your solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent codes other people have posted (I would go with those), this is another (and more readable) way in which you can do the same thing..

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isPalindrome(unsigned number) {
    std::vector<unsigned> number_as_vec;
    while (number) {
        number_as_vec.push_back(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0, j = number_as_vec.size() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (number_as_vec.at(i) != number_as_vec.at(j)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc) {
    unsigned num = 1;
    while (num != 10001) {
        if (isPalindrome(num)) {
            std::cout << num << "\n";
        }
        num++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Also, instead of using vectors, one can simply use a string here:

```
bool isPalindrome(unsigned number) {
    std::string num_as_string(std::to_string(number));
    for (size_t i = 0, j = number_as_string.size() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (number_as_string.at(i) != number_as_string.at(j)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A note: `std::vector` is vast and massive overkill for this job, but the approach is pretty good. Note the `i < j` in the `for` loop's exit condition. You don't have to reverse and you don't have test more than half of the number.  All you have to do is test the outermost digits and keep testing until they meet at the middle (palindrome) or you get a digit mismatch (not a palindrome). This can be done with a single `for` loop and a couple integer variables for book-keeping.

Comment: Explanation is for anyone who comes in the future. You have most of the right idea. A `std::string` replaces the `std::vector` and `std::to_string` parses the number into digits for you.